# Casting after using linq to DataSet

Tags: c#, linq, casting, dataset

I did the following linq query

```
var results = from myRow in QCAllDataSet.DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                                      where myRow.Field<String>("ESRNumber") == value
                                      select new ESR(myRow.ESRNumber,
                                                           myRow.CreationDate,
                                                           myRow.Subsystem,
                                                           myRow.Name,
                                                           myRow.Product,
                                                           myRow.Version,
                                                           myRow.ESRStatus,
                                                           myRow.Owner,
                                                           myRow.Priority,
                                                           myRow.LastPHNote,
                                                           myRow.LastPHNoteDate,
                                                           myRow.LastPHNoteUser,
                                                           myRow.DaysFromLastUpdate,
                                                           myRow.Customer,
                                                           myRow.T2Owner,
                                                           myRow.T2Group,
                                                           myRow.comment,
                                                           myRow.ESRAge);
```

And I would like to convert `results` to `ESR` Object

somthig like `ESR t=(ESR)results`

but I get the following error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection to ESR

How should I Cas this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `select` with LINQ you are getting back a collection, even if you intend to retrieve only a single result.  To indicate a single result, use the `Single()` LINQ method:

```
ESR t = results.Single();
```

If it could possibly return no results (no matches), then you can use `SingleOrDefault()` and check for null:

```
ESR t = results.SingleOrDefault();
if (t == null)
    // could not find match
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FirstOrDefault` to get only one item from the results.

```
var esrObject=  (from myRow in QCAllDataSet.DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
 where myRow.Field<String>("ESRNumber") == value
  select new ESR(myRow.ESRNumber,
                  myRow.CreationDate,
                  myRow.Subsystem)).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can use `SingleOrDefault`  when you are sure your collection will return only one record, Otherwise use FirstOrDefault. `FirstOrDefault` will return first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements. So you dont need to worry even if your collection expression returns more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

An `Enumerable<T>` is not a single object, even if it contains only one. You have to specify what you want. There are plenty of [extension methods in `Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx) like:

- [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) or [Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549138.aspx)
- [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) or [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) which are self explanatory
- [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) or [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) which is most likely what you want([difference of First and Single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724096/linq-single-vs-first))

For example:

```
List<ESR> allESR = results.ToList();
ESR firstESR = results.First(); // throws an exception if there is not at least one
ESR firstESR = results.FirstOrDefault(); // returns null if there's not at least one
```

**Note** that the query is not executed until you call one of these methods(or use a `foreach to iterate them)` due to LINQ's [deferred execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq).