# With Entity Framework is it better to use .First() or .Take(1) for "TOP 1"?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

We are implementing some EF data repositories, and we have some queries which would include `TOP 1`

I have read many posts suggesting to use `.Take(1)` 
The code I'm reviewing uses `.First()`

I understand that both of these produce the same result for the object assignment, but do they both actually resolve to the same query? When the DB is queried, will it actually be with `TOP 1` for both requests? Or will they execute the query in full into the enumerable, then simply take the first entry in the collection?

Furthermore, if we used `.FirstOrDefault()` then why should we expect any different behavior? I know that when using an IEnumerable, calling `.First()` on an empty collection will throw, but if this *is* actually only changing the query to include `TOP 1` then I should expect absolutely no functional difference between `.First()` and `.FirstOrDefault()`.... right?

Alternatively, is there some better method than these Enumerable extentions for making the query execute `TOP 1`?

Comment: How do you turn your `.Take(1)` query into an object?

Comment: Use `First()` if you want an item. Use `Take(1)` if you want a single-item sequence.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

From [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net):

**C#**:

```
age_Centers.Select(c => c.Id).First();
age_Centers.Select(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault();
age_Centers.Select(c => c.Id).Take(1).Dump();
```

**SQL**:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Id]
FROM [age_Centers] AS [t0]
GO

SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Id]
FROM [age_Centers] AS [t0]
GO

SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Id]
FROM [age_Centers] AS [t0]
```

*Note that `Take(1)` enumerates and returns an `IQueryable`.

Comment: What about query.Skip(10).Take(1) ?  Are those three queries the same?

Answer (score 5):

Redirect the DataContext [Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property to Console.Out or a TextFile and see what query each option produces.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No, it wasn't. I think it's a valid answer. I am telling the OP how to find the answer by himself; easily.

Comment: How can I do this when my context is the edmx? It doesn't expose a .Log property.

Comment: @MatthewPK Aren't you asking for the SQL generated by each of the three options you presented? See answer from Ken. That's what you really are looking for.

Comment: linqpad is also a great option

Answer (score 2):

How `.First()` works:

> If the collection is of type IList, then the first element is accessed by index position which is different depending on the collection implementation. Otherwise, an iterator returns the first element.

And `.Take(int count)` always iterate.

If there's any gain, it happens if the collection implements `IList` and the speed to access the first element by index is higher than that of returning an iterator. I don't believe it will be significant. ;)

Sources:

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/FirstOperator.ashx

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/TakeOperator.ashx

Comment: I know that's how `.First()` works in an enumerable. I am asking in the context of the query produced here.

Answer (score 1):

First will query Take 1, so there is no difference in query. Calling FirstOrDefault will be one step statement, because Take returns IEnumerable do you will need to call First anyway.

First will throw exception so FirstOrDefault is always preferred.

And ofcourse people who wrote EF query converter are smart enough to call Take 1 instead executing entire result set and returning first item.

You can this verify using SQL profiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
**First()** operates on a collection of any number of objects and returns the first object.        **Take(1)** operates on a collection of any number of objects and returns a collection containing the first object.
```

You can also use Single
    **Single()** operates on a collection of exactly one object and simply returns the object.

Comment: Related: [LINQ Single vs First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724096/linq-single-vs-first)

Comment: Single operations on a collection period, size doesn't matter. It returns a single result if that result is unique to the collection.