# Get the element from hashset where hashset.Count==1

Tags: c#

How to get the element from hashset that is known to contain exactly 1 element?
(without iterating it)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use **[Single()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.8)**

```
var element = yourHashSet.Single();
```

Comment: But it is (a form of) iterating.

Comment: And requires LINQ that answer should suggest.

Comment: Ref. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724096/linq-single-vs-first#answer-2724246) to whether `.First()` or `.Single()` should be used, I'd suggest using `.Single()` rather than `.First()` -- seeing as getting the knowingly only item in the hash set is the intent here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `HashSet<object>` that for some reason couldn't be accessed with `[0]` or `.First()`.

Though technically iterating, I'm leaving this here just in case someone else with my issue runs into this post.

```
foreach (var i in myHash){
    object o = i;
    break;
}
```

Simply start to iterate, then immediately break the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers above are correct. It seems the only way to access the contents of `HashSet<T>` is through its enumerator.

That said, not all enumerators are made equal.
If you are concerned with garbage allocation, It's preferable to use foreach over single. The reason being that Linq may call `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` which returns an `IEnumerator<T>`. This boxes the enumerator.

You can avoid this by calling `HashSet<T>`, which returns a HashSet.Enumerator. This is a struct and does not allocate.

The [answer by Randy Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793020/get-the-element-from-hashset-where-hashset-count-1/71028674#71028674) already does this (foreach doesn't use IEnumerable, it calls the method directly). But if you'd rather not stick a foreach loop in your code, you can do the iteration manually.

```
var set = new HashSet<String>();
set.Add("foo");

using var enumerator = set.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
var result = enumerator.Current;

Console.Writeline(result); // "foo"
```

Keep in mind that for sets of Count != 1, this is not guaranteed to return the same element each time