# find records in model looking non primary columns

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to make a query in asp.net models.

Im understand we can get a record by a primary key with `ModelContext.Table.Find(id)`, and a  list of all items with `ModelContext.Table.ToList()`...

My question is, how i can get a single item and entire list of items looking in another columns? for example name and lastname.

Something like `ModelContext.Table.Find(new {name = "Stefan", lastname = "Luv"})` and `ModelContext.Table.FindAll(new {"country"="usa"})`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Where](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx):

```
ModelContext.Table.Where(item => item.lastname == "Luv" && item.name == "stefan").ToList();
```

This is a specific example but you can of course set many kinds of predicates in the where expression.

If you want a single unique item, you can use [Single()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
ModelContext.Table.Single(item => item.lastname == "Luv" && item.name == "stefan");
```

Note this will throw an [exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.100).aspx) in case there is more than one row that satisfies your predicate.

Comment: Also see this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724096/linq-single-vs-first