# Selecting a child node having specific value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to check that if the "< city>" node 'having a specific value (say Pathankot )'  already exist in the xml file under the a particular "< user Id="any"> having a specific Id",  before inserting a new city node into the xml.

```
< users> 
     < user Id="4/28/2015 11:29:44 PM"> 
          <city>Fazilka</city> 
          <city>Pathankot </city> 
          <city>Jalandher</city> 
          <city>Amritsar</city> 
     </user> 
</users>
```

In order to insert I am using the Following c# code

```
 XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Ajax\Documents\UserSelectedCity.xml");
        string usrCookieId = Request.Cookies["CookieId"].Value;
xmlDocument.Element("Users")
            .Elements("user")
.Single(x => (string)x.Attribute("Id") == usrCookieId)
             //Incomplete because same named cities can be entered more that once 
             //need to make delete function
            .Add(
            new XElement("city", drpWhereToGo.SelectedValue));
```

My Questions:

- How Can i check weather the < city> node having specific value say
  Pathankot  already exist in the xml file Before Inserting a new city
  node.
- I am Using absolute Path in"    `XDocument xmlDocument =

  XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Ajax\Documents\Visual Studio

  2012\WebSites\punjabtourism.com\UserSelectedCity.xml");"`  This
  does not allow me to move the files to new folder without changing
  the path which is not desirable. But if i use the relative path The
  Error Occures "Access Denied";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

First load the XML file into `XDocument` object by specifying the physical path where your XML file is present. Once you have the object just take the `First` node with matching condition (please note I am using First instead of Single cz you may have multiple nodes with same matching condition, Please see the Difference between [Single & First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724096/linq-single-vs-first))

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"YourPhysicalPath");
xmlDocument.Descendants("user").First(x => (string)x.Attribute("Id") == "1"
                   && x.Elements("city").Any(z => z.Value.Trim() == "Pathankot"))
                 .Add(new XElement("city", drpWhereToGo.SelectedValue));
xmlDocument.Save("YourPhysicalPath");
```

Finally add the required city to the node retrieved from the query and save the XDocument object.

**Update:**

If you want to check first if all the criteria fulfills then simply use `Any` like this:-

```
bool isCityPresent = xdoc.Descendants("user").Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("Id") == "1"
                  && x.Elements("city").Any(z => z.Value.Trim() == "Pathankot"));
```

Comment: Can i use this expression under If() Like 'If(xmlDocument.Descendants("user").First(x => (string)x.Attribute("Id") == "1"
                   && x.Descendants("city").Any(z => z.Value.Trim() == "Pathankot"))'{  //Then Do not make an entry }

Comment: @AnilKumar - Nope because it will return an `XElement` not a boolean if you want to check that first then use my updated code.

Comment: Thanx It works well! Would You mind answering my second Question?

Comment: @AnilKumar - I didn't get your second question. What is the issue you can give the physical path where XML is present and save to whatever location you want.

Comment: Yeah i'm giving the absolute path in XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"YourPhysicalPath"); if the wesite folder is moved to some other directory i need to modify the PhysicalPath appropriately. I dont want to do so. Any alternative from giving the PhysicalPath.?

Comment: Did you try running this code? It only adds "Pathankot" when it already **exists** in the XML and it fails it is not there. This code doesn't work.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Yeah i tried and its working as expected. OP wants to add only when `City exists` for particular user please check the first line.

Comment: @AnilKumar - Okay in that case you should be using `Server.MapPath` but it will only work if the desired XML is already present in your Web Application project.

Comment: It's also lazy using `.Descendants(...)` this way. If the structure of the email is changed (or more detailed than we've been told) then this can fail.

Comment: @RahulSingh - He wants to check if the city exists **before** inserting it - meaning he will only insert it if it **doesn't** exist. I believe he could have made his intent clearer though.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Okay agree with your point of using `Descendants`. Thanks and lets wait for OP to clear his requirement rather than guessing and arguing:)

Comment: if  (!isCityPresent){//Then Make an entry} I'm using it in this way and its working.

Comment: Speak Up @DownVoters! Don't just blindly downvote if you don't have anything to say!

Answer (score 1):

I would use this simple approach:

```
var query =
    xmlDocument
        .Root
        .Elements("user")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("Id").Value == usrCookieId)
        .Where(x => !x.Elements("city").Any(y => y.Value == "Pathankot"));

foreach (var xe in query)       
{
    xe.Add(new XElement("city", drpWhereToGo.SelectedValue));
}
```

It's best to avoid using `.Single(...)` or `.First(...)` if possible. The description of your problem doesn't sound like you need to use these though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an extension to clean it up a bit, and use XPath for the search.

```
public static class MyXDocumentExtensions
{
    public static bool CityExists(this XDocument doc, string cityName)
    {
        //Contains
        //var matchingElements = doc.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("//city[contains(text(), '{0}')]", cityName));
        //Equals
        var matchingElements = doc.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("//city[text() = '{0}']", cityName));

        return matchingElements.Count() > 0;
    }
}
```

And call it like that:

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("xml.txt");
var exists = xmlDocument.CityExists("Amritsar");
```

Expanding on your question in the comment, you can then use it as:

```
if(!xmlDocument.CityExists("Amritsar"))
{
    //insert city
}
```

If you would like to match regardless of the trailing whitespace in the XML, you can wrap the text() call in XPath with a normalize-space:

```
var matchingElements = doc.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("//city[normalize-space(text()) = '{0}']", cityName.Trim()));
```

Comment: Does Not Contain a definition for XPathSelectElements. do i have to use any directive or assembly refrence?

Comment: Yes, you need to add: using System.Xml.XPath

Comment: Ok It works well But can we use the xPath under more specific constraints.I mean to say in the above code we are finding all city nodes having the specified cityname. But what if we need to Find the city Having specific cityname under a particular <user id="Specific user id"> having a specific user Id

Comment: @AnilKumar `//user[@id='user_id_here']/city[.='cityname_here']`

Comment: Ok one more Question! What If we need to print all the elements selected by xpath. using foreach

Comment: matchingElements.ToList().ForEach(el => el.Value)

Comment: Thanks! any reference to learn more about xPath in Linq to xml?