# how to show a single value of column razor view

Tags: select, razor, view

here is my markup

```
    <td class="subtotal">@Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Select(s=>s.targetxyz.wcc)</td>
    <td class="subtotal">@Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Sum(s=>s.wcc.col1)</td>
   <td class="subtotal">@Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Sum(s=>s.wcc.col2)</td>
    <td class="subtotal">@Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Sum(s=>s.wcc.col3)</td>
    <td class="subtotal">@Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Sum(s=>s.wcc.col4)</td>
    <td class="subtotal">@Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Sum(s=>s.wcc.col5)</td>
    <td class="subtotal">@Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Sum(s=>s.wcc.col6)</td>
    <td class="subtotal">@Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Sum(s=>s.wcc.col7)</td>
    <td class="subtotal">@Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Sum(s=>s.wcc.col8)</td>

</tr>
```

my query

```
var data =
             from b in re.wccs
             join t in re.targetxyz on b.xyz equals t.dname
             select new val { wcc = b, targetxyz = t };


        return View(data);
```

my error

System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[db.Models.val,System.Int32]

i can load all the columns with sum but at the place of select command i get this error.

why any suggestion?

Comment: In the first row, the output of the `Select(...)` is an enumerable, not a single object.

Comment: how can i write single object there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use First or Single to get that value, and possible some ordering on data (as not sure what you want to show here)

e.g.

```
    @Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Select(s=>s.targetxyz.wcc).FirstOrDefault()

    @Model.Where(s=>s.wcc.xyz=="abc").Select(s=>s.targetxyz.wcc).SingleOrDefault()
```

read here for difference of single & first:
[LINQ Single vs First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724096/linq-single-vs-first)