# How to select name corresponding the id using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select, where-clause

I have a class points.cs which has members :

```
  public class Points
    {
        public int Id = 0;
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


I have a list of these points like this `List<Points> list= new List<Points>();`
```

Now this list object contains data:

list:

```
 Id    Name
  1    abc
  2    def
  3    ghi
  4    jkl
```

What i have to do is to get the Name corresponding to the id number providing in my code using LINQ query from list object.

My try which os obviously wrong is:

```
 string nameFetchedId=list.Select(Name).Where(obj=>obj.Id=2) //result returned will be "def"
```

Please correct me, I am not good in LINQ ?

Comment: `list.Single(o => o.Id == 2).Name` ?

Comment: @David if list is empty this code will throw exception.

Comment: @Lepijohnny: Correct.  And there are a variety of ways to handle that, depending on what that means to the business logic being invoked.  Which is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @David agree with you, it was just a observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greetings you may want to go like this using lambda expression:

```
string strName = list.where( x => x.id == 2).SingleOrDefault()?.Name;
```

Goodluck

Comment: Be careful about null reference.

Answer (score 6):

Your query needs to be:

```
string name = list.SingleOrDefault(obj => obj.Id == 2)?.Name; // ?. will prevent the code from throwing a null-reference exception and will return null when a point with Id = 2 does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
string nameFetchedId=list.SingleOrDefault(obj=>obj.Id==2)?.Name;
```

First you find your object, then select its Name :)

Answer (score 0):

Selects first that meats the condition return null if not found

```
list.SingleOrDefault(obj=>obj.Id == 2); 
list.FirstOrDefault(obj=>obj.Id == 2);
```

in c# 6 use so you don't have to check if item is found

```
list.SingleOrDefault(obj=>obj.Id == 2)?.Name; 
list.FirstOrDefault(obj=>obj.Id == 2)?.Name;
```

this will return null or the Name value.

Selects first that meats the condition throws exception if not found

```
list.Single(obj=>obj.Id == 2);
list.First(obj=>obj.Id == 2);
```

with this it's safe to use 
    list.Single(obj=>obj.Id == 2).Name;
    list.First(obj=>obj.Id == 2).Name;
You will not get null unless the Name is null just an exception.

If you are using some sort of LINQ to data server (EF,NH,Mongo) some solutions will act a bit differently then when doing in memory query
For more info on Single vs First check out [LINQ Single vs First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724096/linq-single-vs-first)