# why this LINQ statement getting error on matching value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list "otherfee" on which I am using a LINQ statement but it is showing error while I am matching o.ShortName

```
 IList <P_OtherFee> otherfee = 
     P_OtherFee.FindByP_ProgramId((int)p_LoanApplication.P_ProgramId);

        int fee = otherfee.Where(o => o.ShortName == 'PROCESSING FEE').Select(o => o);
```

Comment: It would help to provide which error..

Comment: `.Select(o => o);`   LOL    or do you mean, `.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id)`

Comment: What is the expected input and output for this function?

Comment: I guess this is a typo: you should use `"PROCESSING FEE"` instead of `'PROCESSING FEE'`

Comment: You are assigning an object List to an integer. And read the coment of @SebastianHofmann. Your used `'`not `"`

Comment: This question is clearly asking for help to debug, your debugger probably telling you the errors you made. I think you should get used to using it.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the whole `IEnumerable<P_OtherFee>` object to an `int` variable.
You should filter the list and retrieve the property from a single object, but beware that it might be `null`, if nothing is found based on the conditions. 
Here is an example with the ternary operator to assign a default value of `0` in case obj is `null`:

```
P_OtherFee obj = otherFee.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ShortName == "PROCESSING FEE");
int fee = (obj != null) ? obj.Fee : 0;
```

Old-school LINQ syntax might be simpler to read and understand:

```
int fee = (from obj in otherFee 
           where obj.ShortName == "PROCESSING FEE" 
           select obj.Fee).FirstOrDefault();
```

If a match is found, you get one `Fee` value, if there is no result, you get `0`.
This achieves the same result as the previous code, but saves you from writing a null check.

In both cases, you could use `SingleOrDefault(...)` instead of `FirstOrDefault(...)` if you expect exactly one result and want an exception to be raised if more than one result is obtained.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are selecting the all object `(o => o)` and not an int property, you cannot set the result of your `Where` clause in your `fee` variable.

If you want to select one int :

```
int fee = otherfee.Select(o => o.intProperty).FirstOrDefault(o => o.ShortName == "PROCESSING FEE");
```

If you want to select several ints :

```
IEnumerable<int> fee = otherfee.Where(o => o.ShortName == "PROCESSING FEE").Select(o => o.intProperty);
```

And as @Sebastian Hofmann mentionned, you cannot use `''` to declare a string, you have to use `""`.

Comment: I think this code would not work, because you can't implicitely convert `IEnumerable<int>` to `int`... And there's still the `'PROCESSING FEE'` typo.

Comment: That's right, I answered too fast. I will edit my answer.

Comment: The first line of code doesn't compile, while the second one does, but it needs yet a few more lines to check the results and assign one to an int variable.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar It would indeed be more efficient to Select before getting the results. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Single()/SingleOrDefault()` or `First()/FirstOrDefault()` to get `fee` value

```
var feeObj = otherfee.Single(o => o.ShortName == "PROCESSING FEE");  //If otherfee does not contain 'PROCESSING FEE' then it will throw an error
int fee = feeObj.ProcessingFee;
```

Or

```
int? fee = otherfee.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ShortName == "PROCESSING FEE")?.FeeProcessing;
```

Or if you dont want use nullable data type of int then

```
int fee = otherfee.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ShortName == "PROCESSING FEE")?.FeeProcessing ?? 0;
```

You can read difference between Single() and First(): [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2724246/6299857)

In last code, I used `?.` and `??`, more more details read about [navigation operator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/) and [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) in C#.

Comment: The first two lines of code can be dangerous because you aren't handling any of the possible outcomes (SingleOrDefault is a safer option), while the other line of code doesn't compile (but I guess the "?" is a typo).

Comment: @StackLloyd, I already mentioned in comment about possible error while using `single'. `No ?. is not a typo just read about **navigation operator in C#**

Comment: I know about the operator, but this means you also need to declare `fee` as `int?`, which you didn't, and such a cast is unnecessary for such a simple operation.

Comment: You can simplify it with `??`operator: `int fee = otherfee.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ShortName == "PROCESSING FEE")?.FeeProcessing ?? 0;`