# Find First Index of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, excel, ienumerable

I have a method that accepts an IEnumerable as a parameter.
My issue is that this method is sometimes given an array that starts at 1 (instead of 0).

I could just create a list and add the elements of the parameter to it but isn't there a way of just getting the first index?

**EDIT 1:**
What I mean with "an array that starts at 1" is an array that literally starts at 1, for example:
[image]

I cannot access the array "cells" with the line:

```
cells[0, 0]
```

This specific array is being read from an Excel range.

**EDIT 2:**
This isn't the only array that is being given to The method.
The method also receives arrays that start at 0 and it needs to work for all cases.

Comment: What do you mean "an array that starts at 1"? You mean the first value is NULL? Arrays always start with index 0 in C#... You can just do array.Where(a => a != null) to skip the nulls

Comment: What is your mean? An array always starts from 0 index.

Comment: @SaeidBabaei the first items position is always `0` no matter the value of the item

Comment: You can use Skip(1) method to ignore first index

Comment: I edited the question to answer your questions.

Comment: Are you using excel interop?

Comment: Yes, but I'm searching for a general solution to this.

Comment: If you are given an IEnumerable, you shouldn't be assuming it's an array. All you should do is treat it like an IEnumerable (foreach, ToList, ToArray, etc.). And, as mentioned elsewhere, though the Framework supports non-zero lower bounds for an array, all arrays in C# and VB start at index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MartinLiversage pointed out, there is an overload of `Array.CreateInstance` allowing to specify a lower bound:

```
public static Array CreateInstance (Type elementType, int[] lengths, int[] lowerBounds);
```

You have to cast the unspecific `Array` to a concrete type, to able to access its elements directly. Example:

```
var cells =
    (int[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new[] { ROWS, COLUMNS }, new[] { 1, 1 });
```

You can get the bounds with `cells.GetLowerBound(0)` (first dimension) and `cells.GetLowerBound(1)` (second dimension). There is a corresponding `GetUpperBound` method. Example:

```
// Loop through the matrix
for (int i = cells.GetLowerBound(0); i <= cells.GetUpperBound(0); i++) {
    for (int j = cells.GetLowerBound(1); j <= cells.GetUpperBound(1); j++) {
        // Get an element
        var element = cells[i, j];

        // Set an element
        cells[i, j] = value;
    }
}
```

Or, to get the first element only:

```
var result = cells[cells.GetLowerBound(0), cells.GetLowerBound(1)];
```

You can also enumerate the array with `foreach`. This flattens the array, i.e. it treats the array as if it was one-dimensional.

Note, the LINQ extension method `First` always returns the first item, irrespective of the lower bounds of the array.

```
var result = cells.First();
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what do you mean by .

**sometimes given an array that starts at 1**

The arrays must start at the **zero index**, 
I think you mean to try to filter the values and check if null empty values 
you can try the below:

```
var firstValue = array.First(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.value));
```

Or you can remove the first element or any element on a condition

```
array = array.Skip(0);
```

***UPDATE***

When you pass a sub-array to the method, usually it doesn't start at index zero.

So, you can loop on the array to and handle the items after checking if it exists or not using `ElementAtOrDefault() Linq method`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
 {
    if(ElementAtOrDefault(i) != null)
        // your logic
 }
```

Comment: Arrays in .NET can have lower bounds that are not 0.

Comment: Okay, I got your point, this case usually happens when you pass a sub array to the method.

Comment: My comment is about your statement: _The arrays must start at the **zero index**_. This is not true in .NET. You can create arrays with a lower bound that is not 0. If the lower bound is 1 then you access the first element in the array using `array[1]`, not `array[0]`.

Comment: @MartinLiversage yeah, I got your point and I did add a new update to the answer
and you can check if the element exists or not using `ElementAtOrDefault`

Answer (score 2):

Normally arrays have a lower bound of 0. However, you can create arrays with different lower bounds. To do that you need to use [`Array.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Int32___System_Int32___):

```
var array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), new[] { 10 }, new[] { 1 });
```

This will create an one dimensional array with ten elements with a lower bound of 1. Here is how you set the value of the first element:

```
array.SetValue("first", 1);
```

In your case you could use code like this to create a two dimensional array with 10 x 20 elements and lower bounds of 1:

```
var array = (object[,]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new[] { 10, 20 }, new[] { 1, 1 });
```

And to get the lower bound of the first dimension you can use [`GetLowerBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlowerbound?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var lowerBound = array.GetLowerBound(0);
```

Specify 1 as the argument to get the lower bound of the second dimension etc. There is also a `GetUpperBound` method. And in case you don't even know the dimensions of the array you can inspect the `Rank` property.

I believe this feature mostly exist to support porting old Visual Basic code to Visual Basic .NET and interop with COM automation (e.g. Excel) where arrays often have a lower bound of 1.

Comment: This is good to know but doesn't answer my question. I want to be able to identify the lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the need you can use each. Read the link below .

```
 var firstValue = Yourlist.First(x => x.value);
```

or

```
var firstValue = Yourlist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.value);
```

or

```
var firstValue = Yourlist.Single(x => x.value);
```

or

```
var firstValue = Yourlist.SingleOrDefault(x => x.value);
```

[LINQ Single vs First](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26172648/5576498)

Comment: `First` and `Single` take a `Func<TSource, bool>` predicate to filter on like `Where`, not a `Func<TSource, TResult>` selector like `Select`.

Comment: @juharr My answer was before the question was changed. The questioner edited the question text.

Comment: The change in the question has nothing to do with the fact that this code is incorrect unless `value` is of type `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about Excel Interop:

- Indexer - Indexer is 1-base:

  ```
  cells[1,1].Value2 = "something";
  ```
- IEnumerable - Using `Cast` and `First` or `FirstOrDefalt`:

  ```
  cells.Cast<dynamic>().FirstOrDefault().Value2 = "something";
  ```
- IEnumerable - Using `GetEnumerator`:

  ```
  var enumerator  = cells.GetEnumerator();
  enumerator.MoveNext();
  ((dynamic)enumerator.Current).Value2 = "something";
  ```
- If you are interested to know about the column index and row index in the sheet, the `Column` and `Row` property will show the coordinates in the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I'm not looking for a solution specifically for the Excel interop.

Comment: Excel Range is different. You need to treat it differently.

Comment: These are available options when using `IEnumerable`.

Comment: IEnumerable != Array, lowebounds and upperbounds doesn't make sense on it.